# Error occurred when install discord js on CentOS ver 7.9

Tags: node.js, discord.js, centos7

i tried push my bot to remote server but when i install discord js. it give me error like

```
gyp ERR! node -v v16.19.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/root/botV14/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/prebuild/node-v93-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-2.17/opus.node --module_name=opus --module_path=/root/botV14/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/prebuild/node-v93-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-2.17 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/root/botV14/node_modules/@discordjs/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:85:20)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/root/botV14/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /root/botV14/node_modules/@discordjs/opus
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.19.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.4.5
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-06T13_13_38_662Z-debug-0.log
```

and i don't know how to fix this.

i tried install node gyp but it seem like doesn't work

Comment: Do you see more about the error in the log file `/root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-06T13_13_38_662Z-debug-0.log`?

Comment: i readed but it show me same error like i showed there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i knew how to fix this.
try install opusscript instead opus

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).